# HTML Message doesn't show in Outlook, Gmail, etc

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook, gmail

I'm trying to send a table by e-mail, using SMTP Client in c#, and the way is by sending a datatable with the info and turn it into a HTML, I'm sure that the body is working but it only shows the tags:
[E-mail sent Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iwuC.png), I test it by copying that in my vs code and its shows perfectly!

This is my HTML:

```
<font> These are the following records: </font><br><br><table style ="border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;"><tr style = "background-color:#6FA1D2;color:#ffffff;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Information</td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Values</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">PickUp# </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Test1</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Destination </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Test1</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Company# </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Test1</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Trk# </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Test1</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Trl# </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Test1</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Driver's Name </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Test1</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Driver's Phone# </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Test1</td></tr><tr style ="color:#555555;"><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">Check Date & Hour </td><td style="border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;">8/18/2022 12:00:00</td></tr></table>
```

And this is my Method in C# creating the Html:

```
    public static string getHTML(DataTable table)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageBody = "<font> These are the following records: </font><br><br>";
            if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return messageBody;
            }
            string htmlTableStart = "<table style =\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\">";
            string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";

            string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style = \"background-color:#6FA1D2;color:#ffffff;\">";
            string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";

            string htmlTrStart = "<tr style =\"color:#555555;\">";
            string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";

            string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\"border-color:##5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding:5px;\">";
            string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";

            messageBody += htmlTableStart;

            messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "Information" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlTdStart + "Values" + htmlTdEnd;
            messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

            for (int i = 0; i <= table.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrStart;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][0] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + table.Rows[i][1] + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrEnd;
            }
            messageBody = messageBody + htmlTableEnd;
            return messageBody;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I really don't know what is wrong

Method of Sending Mail

```
 public static void Email(string htmlString)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            {
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.Port = 587;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
                {
                    UserName = "myusermname@isp.com",
                    Password = "mypswrd"
                };
            };
            MailAddress fromEmail = new MailAddress("fromemail@mail,com", "DisplayName");
            MailAddress toEmail = new MailAddress("tomail@mail.com");
            MailAddress ccRecipients = new MailAddress("fromemail@mail,com");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
            {
                From = fromEmail,
                Subject = "New Check In Registered",
                Body = htmlString,
            };
            message.Bcc.Add(ccRecipients);
            message.To.Add(toEmail);
            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: We need to see your method that actually sends the email. Can you please include that.

Comment: Seeing the code that actually sends the message body is what we need to see as @mathis1337 stated

Comment: I already edit the original post, sorry, it looks like that the address have comma instead of dot but it is cause I was changing the credentials

Comment: I already fixed i put the : isbodyhtml set to true sorry to bother Thanks